# Can I bind multiple servers to the same TCP port?

Tags: python, port

I would expect having multiple servers on the same port would cause problems. In fact I want it to throw an exception when I try to start two servers on the same port. The problem is, it seems more than happy to start multiple servers on the same port. I can have many instances of the following code running just fine with no exceptions.

```
import BaseHTTPServer
import SimpleHTTPServer
import sys

def main():
    try:
        server = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(('127.0.0.1',5000), SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
        print "On port: " + str(server.socket.getsockname()[1])
    except Exception, e:
        print e
    server.serve_forever()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

All of which claim to be on port 5000. How can I get it to throw an exception if it tries to use a port that is already taken?

Edit: This is Python 2.6.4

Edit 2: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rVOG3JdbHAM&feature=youtu.be Because people seem to think what I am explaining is not possible? Or I am totally misunderstanding people. Either way, this video should clear it up. I start two servers, neither of them print out any exceptions. When I close the first, the second starts working. Why is this happening? I would expect the 2nd server to simply never start and print an exception. Is this not what should happen?

Comment: Umm, you're hiding the exceptions. This will immediately terminate if the initialization fails (`server` won't be set).

Comment: Yeah, I am aware of that. This is just a simple snippet that illustrates my problem of having many servers on the same port.

Comment: You must be mistaken, the underlying os won't allow two processes to open a socket server on the same port. There must be more to the story.

Comment: Running Python 2.7 on Windows 7; I get the same issue.

Comment: Is the code in this question absolutely the only code you are running, or are you paraphrasing?

Comment: This is absolutely the only code I am running. Just to confirm it I 1) copied and pasted it into a new file. 2) ran that file in two different command prompts. 3) saw no exceptions and saw the message On port: 5000 on each. The first console will output messages when I navigate to it. If I close it, the 2nd console will then start printing out the messages as I navigate to it. If I had screen recording software, I would post a video on YouTube :)

Answer (score 1):

I tried to execute your code and the second instance returned,

```
 [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

as it should. Python 2.6 on SuSE Linux.

Can check with netstat utility whether port 5000 is really taken?

Comment: I am running on Windows 7. It lists the ports status as TIME_WAIT.

Comment: Okay, so it is NOT listening. The server did not even start (I don't know why). The port should be in LISTEN mode if displayed with "netstat -na".

Comment: But what is odd is that it still works. If I wait long enough, run netstat again, 127.0.0.1:5000 is not even listed. But if I navigate there in a browser, the correct files are served and the port is again listed as TIME_WAIT. (And if I use a different port no files are served)

Comment: The port working without being in LISTEN would shriek "rootkit!" under any Unix. Maybe windows 7 has a different policy; check out the TCPView utility by SysInternals. Maybe there's some really weird socket multiplexing scheme to allow more servers on a port. Maybe port 5000 is interfered upon by the uPNP subsystem. I'm sorry, I have next to no experience on Windows 7 networking :-(

Answer (score 0):

A TCP port can be bound by one and only one process. As was noted by @phihag, you only think you have multiple servers bound to port 5000 because you are throwing away the exception that would tell you that you already had bound that port.

> I am running on Windows 7. It lists the ports status as TIME_WAIT

That's a secondary problem which is usually caused by clients not shutting down the connection properly. TIME_WAIT is a [valid TCP state](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aTcp_state_diagram_fixed.svg) but one that will take [2 minutes for the server to clear](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_Segment_Lifetime). You should look to why your clients are dropping the connection instead of having the server close it.

If you are using a standard browser on the client side, you should assume you have a second bug in your server code that you've not shown here.

**added in response to comment**

There is something wrong with your expectations. This version of your code should make it clear:

```
def bind():
    return BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(('127.0.0.1',5000), SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)

s1 = bind()
s2 = bind()
```

Where the last line will abort your program with an "Address already in use" exception. If you chose to ignore (or catch and discard) the exception, `s2` will not be have a valid server. This is what the exception is telling you. In C, if you ignored errors the same way it would look like:

```
fp = fopen("a_file_that_does_not_exist", "r")
fgets(buf, BUFSIZ, fp)
```

Both `fopen` and `fgets` will return `EOF` which you are ignoring. The program would run, but it certainly wouldn't do anything useful because you can't read from a file that does not exist. You can ignore the error returns but holding your hands over your eyes doesn't make the monster go away either.

Comment: I must be confused as to what you and phihag mean about throwing away the exception. (New to Python) I thought by having the except block I was catching and printing exceptions raised when starting the server. It seems to correctly capture and print an exception when I set it to a port that netstat lists as ESTABLISHED.

Comment: Catching an exception does **not** handle the exception. Suppose you were opening a file for reading that didn't exist, it would raise an exception. Catching that exception and printing a message would **not** leave you with an readable file, it would let your program continue with an unreadable file "handle". Every `file.read()` would thus fail; therefore, you "caught" the exception but didn't fix the problem of "no file to read". You are doing the same thing here, but files are a little easier to visualize than sockets.

Comment: Ok. So this is still doing what I expect then. I am not trying to actually switch to a backup port in this example. This is just to illustrate that I am not getting any exceptions when I try to open two servers on the port.

Comment: @Justin see "added" above in my answer. Your expectation is wrong.

Comment: So, maybe I am not understanding what my code does here. But What I think SHOULD be happening when I open the 2nd server on the port, I should get an error message that, paraphrased, says something like "Port already in use sucker, I am not going to server nothing for you!". When in fact, what ACTUALLY HAPPENS is I get the message "On port: 5000". And if I close the 1st instance of the server, the 2nd instance continues to work on port 5000. It should not work, but does. Once I can actually make it not work, I can replace the except block with something useful. Like opining a different port.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the various answers and comments indicating that you cannot have multiple listeners to a single TCP port; however, I am experiencing the same behaviour as OP.  I am running Windows 8, and neither instance of my program (written in C++, using Boost) has an exception thrown.  The output from `netstat` looks like:

```
C:\windows\system32>netstat -an

Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:445            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:5357           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:7112           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:17500          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49152          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49153          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49154          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49155          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49157          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:50102          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:50102          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:2559         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:19872        127.0.0.1:49248        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49248        127.0.0.1:19872        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50102        127.0.0.1:52616        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50102        127.0.0.1:52618        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50102        127.0.0.1:52620        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50102        127.0.0.1:52622        TIME_WAIT
```

In this case, the first program instance to start listening to port 50102 receives all the client connections.  Then, when I close that instance, the second instance starts receiving the client connections.  Strange but true.

I was hoping that the second program instance would be unable to start listening to the same port as the first instance.