# Mac OS X - bind a server socket port to all interfaces and prevent other binds with the same port

Tags: java, macos, sockets, network-programming, network-interface

On OS X, when creating a server socket on a specific port for all interfaces, a new server socket can bind to `localhost` with the same port and accept connections.
I would expect the binding to `localhost` to fail, as it does when trying the same in Linux (I tried on Ubuntu specifically).

The behavior on OS X is weird to me, because client connections to `localhost` work when listening on all interfaces, but a new server can bind `localhost` on the same port and accept new connections, instead of the first listener.

How can a socket listen on all interfaces and also prevent other sockets from binding to `localhost` with the same port on OS X?

The following test passes on Mac and fails on Ubuntu, but should fail on both.

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Inet4Address;
import java.net.ServerSocket;

public class MinimalTest {
    @Test
    public void listenOnAllInterfacesAndLocalhost() throws IOException {
        final int port = 12340;
        try (ServerSocket allInterfaces = new ServerSocket(port);
             ServerSocket onlyLocalhost = new ServerSocket(port, 100, Inet4Address.getByName("localhost"));) {
            Assert.assertEquals(allInterfaces.getLocalPort(), port);
            Assert.assertEquals(onlyLocalhost.getLocalPort(), port);

            Assert.assertTrue(allInterfaces.isBound());
            Assert.assertTrue(onlyLocalhost.isBound());
        }
    }
}
```

What I tried:

- Listen on all interfaces explicitly with `Inet4Address.getByName("0.0.0.0")` or `Inet6Address.getByName("::")` but with or without this specification, `lsof` shows listening on all interfaces: `*:12340`
- I switched the order of binding (first `localhost` and then all interfaces) and with binding from different processes, but OS X still allows the binding.
- I searched for a similar problem, but didn't find this problem... [Binding to all interfaces of a single network interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39536172) [multiple interface bind on same port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23778518) [Can I bind multiple servers to the same TCP port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570290) [Can socket client and server on the same computer bind to same port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53956715)